# check if validation fails inside a wizard and a modal dialog in primefaces

Tags: validation, dialog, primefaces, modal-dialog, wizard

This is my attempt to check if my validation fails after the "Next" button is pressed inside a wizard. This is done in oncomplete - At the moment I'm just showing a JS alert message that shows a value of undefined. I don't think the backend bean is relevant here as validation is triggered via required=true - No further checks are made in the bean.

Current behaviour: Alert box shows "undefined, then a validation error message is showed "Password cannot be blank"

Expected behaviour: Alert box shows "true", then  a validation error message is showed "Password cannot be blank"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">


<h:head>

</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form prependId="false">

        <p:dialog id="modalDialog" header="add user" widgetVar="userDialog" modal="true" width="640"
                  height="400" closable="true" appendToBody="true" visible="true">
            <p:growl id="growl" sticky="true" showDetail="true"/>
            <p:wizard widgetVar="wiz" effect="fade"
                      flowListener="#{userWizard.onFlowProcess}" showStepStatus="true" showNavBar="false" onback="progressBack();" >

                <p:tab id="personal" title="Personal" >
                    <p:messages severity="warn" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" redisplay="true" />
                    <p:messages id="dialog_msgs" showDetail="false" autoUpdate="true" redisplay="true"/>
                    <p:panel style="height:150px;" >
                        <h:panelGrid columnClasses="label" columns="6" cellpadding="5">
                            <p:column>
                                <h:outputText value="Password: " styleClass="label" />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column>
                                <p:password value="${userWizard.user.password}" styleClass="content" required="true"
                                            requiredMessage="Password cannot be blank"/>
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column style="width: 50;">
                                <h:outputText value=" "/>
                            </p:column>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                        <h:panelGroup>

                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </p:panel>
                    <p:commandButton value="Previous"  disabled="true" readonly="true" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Next"  oncomplete="alert(args.validationFailed); wiz.next();"  update="dialog_msgs" ajax="true" process="@this" />
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab id="personal2" title="Personal">
                    Not relevant
                    <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="growl messages @form"
                                     actionListener="#{userWizard.save}"/>

                </p:tab>
            </p:wizard>
        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```